# AngularJS bootstrap modal scope value not displayed

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular bootstrap modal.

`termsText` is populated and the `scope.productTerms` does contain a value. But for some reason when I output `{{ productTerms }}` inside the modal the value is not being displayed. Why?

js

```
$scope.openProductTerms = function (termsText) {
    $scope.productTerms = termsText <-- has a value in console.log()
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalTerms.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
});




var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('OK');
    };
};
```

html

```
{{ productTerms }} < ==== value shows outside modal


<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalTerms.html">
    <div class="modal-body">

        {{ productTerms }}  <==== same value does not show insdie modal?

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: The modal has a new controller and therefore a new scope. This might be helpful https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

Comment: You should be able to specify a scope when you open a modal.

Comment: @Zack Argyle the scope is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal has a new controller and therefore a new scope.
services.js

```
 angular.module('services',[]).
  factory('sharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};   
    sharedService.value = null;

   sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(value) {
       this.value = value;
       this.broadcastItem();
   };

   sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
       $rootScope.$broadcast('shared');
   };

   return sharedService;
 });
```

controller.js

```
     $scope.openProductTerms = function (termsText) {
          sharedService.prepForBroadcast(termsText);
       var modalInstance = $modal.open({
       templateUrl: 'myModalTerms.html',
       controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
     });
```

lastController.js

```
     var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance,sharedService) {
        $scope.$on('shared', function() {
    $scope.productTerms = sharedService.value;
    });
       $scope.ok = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('OK');
        };
     };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `{{$parent.productTerms}}` within your HTML

From my experience, it seems that the angular bootstrap modal creates a new scope. So by referencing `$parent` first, you'll be able to get your model's value.